# Set min and max constraints on the number of items in the Knapsack problem

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, knapsack-problem, or-tools

How do I set a constraint on the minimum and maximum (or just a fixed constant) amount of items in the knapsack using the google or tools solver?

I would also happily take any suggestions for solutions that do not use the Google ORTools solver...

```
from ortools.algorithms import pywrapknapsack_solver
solver = pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver(
    pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver.
    KNAPSACK_MULTIDIMENSION_BRANCH_AND_BOUND_SOLVER, 'KnapsackExample')

values = [10, 15,1, 5, 7]
weights = [ [4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
capacities = [ 6, 4 ]
solver = pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver(
        pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver
        .KNAPSACK_MULTIDIMENSION_BRANCH_AND_BOUND_SOLVER,
        'Multi-dimensional solver')
solver.Init(values, weights, capacities)
computed_value = solver.Solve()
packed_items = []
packed_weights = []
total_weight = 0
print('Total value =', computed_value)
for i in range(len(values)):
    if solver.BestSolutionContains(i):
        packed_items.append(i)
        packed_weights.append(weights[0][i])
        total_weight += weights[0][i]
print('Total weight:', total_weight)
print('Packed items:', packed_items)
print('Packed_weights:', packed_weights)
```

Comment: Imho this customized solver is relatively *specialized* without side-constraint support. You can always model your problem in one of ortools' generic/general-purpose solver (interfaces): either as mixed-integer linear-program or with cp-sat.

Comment: hi @sascha, thanks for your reply. I looked at cp-sat but literally have no idea how I can apply what I'm doing here to that, I couldn't even work out how you assign arrays as variables etc

Comment: There are many many examples to learn from (apart from the docs). Maybe start with [multiple_knapsack_sat.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/samples/multiple_knapsack_sat.py). I'm afraid, you will need to be more explicit about your problems (after you worked through the examples).